# List of Ruby Metaprogramming methods?

Tags: ruby, object, reflection, methods, metaprogramming

Just started learning Ruby metaprogramming. Looking at Object.methods I get:

```
Object.methods => [
:allocate, 
:new, 
:superclass, 
:freeze, 
:===, 
:==, 
:<=>, 
:<, 
:<=, 
:>, 
:>=, 
:to_s, 
:included_modules, 
:include?, 
:name, 
:ancestors, 
:instance_methods, 
:public_instance_methods, 
:protected_instance_methods, 
:private_instance_methods, 
:constants, 
:const_get, 
:const_set, 
:const_defined?, 
:const_missing, 
:class_variables, 
:remove_class_variable, 
:class_variable_get, 
:class_variable_set, 
:class_variable_defined?, 
:module_exec, 
:class_exec, 
:module_eval, 
:class_eval, 
:method_defined?, 
:public_method_defined?, 
:private_method_defined?, 
:protected_method_defined?, 
:public_class_method, 
:private_class_method, 
:autoload, 
:autoload?, 
:instance_method, 
:public_instance_method, 
:nil?, 
:=~, 
:!~, 
:eql?, 
:hash, 
:class, 
:singleton_class, 
:clone, 
:dup, 
:initialize_dup, 
:initialize_clone, 
:taint, 
:tainted?, 
:untaint, 
:untrust, 
:untrusted?, 
:trust, 
:frozen?, 
:inspect, 
:methods, 
:singleton_methods, 
:protected_methods, 
:private_methods, 
:public_methods, 
:instance_variables, 
:instance_variable_get, 
:instance_variable_set, 
:instance_variable_defined?, 
:instance_of?, 
:kind_of?, 
:is_a?, 
:tap, 
:send, 
:public_send, 
:respond_to?, 
:respond_to_missing?, 
:extend, 
:display, 
:method, 
:public_method, 
:define_singleton_method, 
:__id__, 
:object_id, 
:to_enum, 
:enum_for, 
:equal?, 
:!, 
:!=, 
:instance_eval, 
:instance_exec, 
:__send__]
```

Is there a list of methods that are useful for metaprogramming? Such as `instance_eval`, `initialize` and `method_missing`?

Comment: If metaprogramming Ruby is a serious interest, I strongly recommend the [Metaprogramming Ruby book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) by Paolo Perrotta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the top answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127819/is-this-a-comprehensive-list-of-ruby-hook-methods) page :

**Method-related hooks**

```
method_missing
method_added
singleton_method_added
method_removed
singleton_method_removed
method_undefined
singleton_method_undefined
```

**Class & Module Hooks**

```
inherited
append_features
included
extend_object
extended
initialize_copy
const_missing
```

**Marshalling Hooks**

```
marshal_dump
marshal_load
```

**Coercion Hooks**

```
coerce
induced_from
to_xxx
```

Also, check [this](http://khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-callbacks/) blog post for explanations and sample code for many of these methods.

Comment: Note that these are great hooks, but do not include things like `instance_eval` or `define_method`.

Answer (score 5):

`Object` is a class, so most of the methods you listed are actually `Class` instance methods. Look also at `Object.private_methods` -- you will find `define_method` in there, which is absolutely essential. But `binding` is very powerful too... when learning about Ruby metaprogramming, you'll want to look at the docs for the `Binding` class. The `send`, `__send__`, and `public_send` family is also essential.

Looking at the above list, you should be able to identify the "reflection" methods which can be used to query and manipulate constants, methods, instance variables, and so on programmatically. Then there are the `eval` and `exec` methods. `method_missing` is one of the first ones you learn, but pay attention to `const_missing` also. Make sure to check out `set_trace_func` and `trace_var`. And where would we be without `alias` and `alias_method`?

Then there are the interpreter "hooks" like `method_added`, `method_removed`, `method_undefined`, `inherited`, `extended`, `included`, `singleton_method_added`, `singleton_method_removed`, `singleton_method_undefined`, `instance_method_added`, `instance_method_removed`, and `instance_method_undefined`.

`Object#method` is essential for getting `Method` objects. Look at all the methods of `Method`, including things like `owner`. `Kernel#caller` can be useful sometimes. Then also look up the `ObjectSpace` class.

Understand that although they have some special behavior, classes and modules are just objects and you can create them dynamically, store them in data structures, etc. They don't even have to have names. You can just call `Class.new` to make a new one and use `class_eval`, `define_method`, etc. as needed to add methods to it.

`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` can be interesting, especially `File.read(__FILE__)`.

Understanding blocks and lambdas well is important both for general Ruby programming, and for metaprogramming in particular.

Answer (score 2):

In the book "Metaprogramming Ruby", the author states that there's no firm line between metaprogramming and programming. It's all just programming.

Some examples I can think of that are somewhat in-between programming and metaprogramming are `class` and `attr_reader`.