# How to DRY two slightly different forms?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

I know about partial in rails, but it seems that I can only re-use exactly the same form with partial.

What if I have two forms that differ only in one field? For example, in my classroom app, I have one form for a peer-grader and one form for a teacher-grader.

The teacher's form is as follows. The peer-grader form is exactly the same, minus the `grade` field. How do I DRY this?

```
<%= form_for @doc, 
          url: student_homework_document_path(student_id: @doc.submitter_id,
                                               id: @doc.id),
          html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :grade %>
      <%= f.number_field :grade %>

      <%= f.label :graded_file %>
      <%= f.file_field :graded_file %>

      <%= f.label :graded_file_source_code %>
      <%= f.file_field :graded_file_source_code %>

      <%= f.submit "Submit grading", class: "btn btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Are they actually exactly the same? Do they use the same controller method?

Comment: In this case, yes it's the same `edit` controller method. Does this matter generally? The most common example of rails partial use the same partials for `new` and `edit`.

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer to this myself. Metaprogramming seems promising as a way to DRY up your two forms, but I don't know enough about it to suggest a specific solution. Here's a good discussion on the topic: .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490818/list-of-ruby-metaprogramming-methods.

Comment: Sorry the post request for the form, so whatever `url: your_path_here` is set to.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you had one controller called teachers and one called peers or something. You could keep the form the same but add a variable to the peer-grader method such as `@peer_grader = true`. Then in your form add:

```
<% if @peer_grader = true %>
  <%= f.label :grade %>
  <%= f.number_field :grade %>
<% end %>
```

You would also need to set another variable called @url in both controllers set to the correct path and then update the form to:

```
<%= form_for @doc, url: @url, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```